# How to define and render sections conditionally in Layout

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, razor

How can one define a section and render it immediately in the layout page?

//_Layout.cshtml

```
<header>
@section sb233{
    <div class="somecontent">
    @ViewBag.somecontent
    </div>
}
@if (ViewBag.sb233) { RenderSection("sb233"); }
</header>
//Main container
<footer>@RenderSection("footer",false)</footer>
```

//aView.cshtml

```
@{
  ViewBag.sb233=false; 
  ViewBag.somecontent="sb233";
 }
//Page content
@section footer { @RenderSection("sb233");}
```

//anotherView.cshtml

```
@{ViewBag.sb233=true;}
//Page content
@section footer { Something else}
```

Gives me a "Section Not Defined" error.

The reason for the section to be defined in the layout rather than the view is it is a common recurring section and to allow the view to control whether and where the section should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it a bit too difficult for yourself.
You want to show the specified section based on a viewbag property, you could do it withouth a RenderSection.

//_Layout.cshtml

```
<header>
@if (ViewBag.sb233)
{
    <div class="somecontent">
    @ViewBag.somecontent
    </div>
}
</header>
//Main container
<footer>@RenderSection("footer",false)</footer>
```

//aView.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.sb233=false; 
 }
//Page content
@section footer { }
```

//anotherView.cshtml

```
@{
   ViewBag.sb233=true;
   ViewBag.somecontent="sb233";
}
//Page content
@section footer { }
```

Just for your knowledge, your anotherView.cshtml page returns an error because it expects your view to have a section sb233 defined. But you don't have that.
The error would be fixed when you change your _Layout.cshtml line to:

```
@if (ViewBag.sb233) { RenderSection("sb233", false); }
```

Comment: I am aware to use sections here makes things hard but the views are not just for myself but for ppl who only knows html to edit their text and html contents. Using viewbag only will stringify the raw html and breaking up the text structure and impair the readability and ease of editing for those ppl who are only html literate.

Comment: Does changing this: RenderSection("sb233"); to this: RenderSection("sb233", false); work?